# Using - in names of table or database

Tags: mysql

i have imported an old mysql database and this database has table names containing -(hyphen) but in the table names nowadays mysql does not accept table names with -(hyphen). Is there any way around.

the name of tables are like Bx-Books.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can change table name inside the ``(back tick) in your table name:

```
  Create  table `Bx-Books`....
```

Comment: i have already imported the database. Other than that any way?

Comment: @user2598085, just escape it in your select query like `select * from `Bx-Books``. That's should just be fine.

Comment: Then you need to change your query's(insert,select,update..) table name like this \`Bx-Books\`

Comment: it doesn't accept says to such table exists ' select * from Bx-Books; '

Comment: you can use like this select * from \`Bx-Books\`;

Comment: mysql> select Book-Title from 'bx_books';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''bx_b
ooks'' at line 1